# How do I display a Text element inside a parent View over an ImageBackground in React Native on iOS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a screen in react native which contains a background image, I want to put text on top of this background image but the text will not be visible so I wrap the Text component with a View component. How do i make the text render on iOs?

I am running react native using the expo cli, the react native is sdk-32. The text renders fine on android. When i remove the view component, the text renders fine on iOs

```
<ImageBackground source={require('../assets/launch3.jpg')} style={{ height: '100%', paddingLeft: '6%', paddingRight: '6%' }}>
<View style={{ width: '100%', height: '15%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)', borderRadius: 5, marginTop: '90%' }}>
<Text style={{ width: '90%', alignSelf: 'center', textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 18, color: '#005F6A', marginTop: '5%' }}>
"Text to display"
</Text>
</View>
</ImageBackground>
```

I expect the text "Text to display" to be rendered on iOs but instead only the View wrapping it is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the position attribute to absolute in the View tag that contains the Text tag.

```
<ImageBackground source={require('../assets/launch3.jpg')} style={{ height: '100%', paddingLeft: '6%', paddingRight: '6%' }}>
<View style={{ position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '15%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)', borderRadius: 5, marginTop: '90%' }}>
<Text style={{ width: '90%', alignSelf: 'center', textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 18, color: '#005F6A', marginTop: '5%' }}>
"Text to display"
</Text>
</View>
</ImageBackground>
```